# Polymer-element 0px x 0px

Tags: polymer

I went through the [Setting Up Bower and Polymer][1] video - copied code exactly, but get a "polymer-element 0px x 0px" and "x-foo 0px x 0px" error. How come? Help!

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
</head>
<body>
<polymer-element name="x-foo" noscript>
  <template>
    <style>
      h1 {
        color: orange;
      }
    </style>
    <h1>Hello from x-foo</h1>
  </template>
</polymer-element>

<x-foo></x-foo>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default custom elements are `display: inline`. To be block level you should style the `:host` with `display: block;` in your shadow dom:

```
:host {
  display: block;
}
```

https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/articles/styling-elements.html#element-defined-styles

Comment: Thanks for replying ebidel. I tried this but got the same result. Is it possible I've installed something incorrectly or not installed something that I need? I'm using Chrome version 41.0.2272.118 and running on my local server. I've copied the exact same code as @robdodson used in the video (which didn't have the ':host' code.

Comment: @ToughTimes what result would be ideal? Do you want `x-foo` to represent the area taken up by `h1`?

Comment: Is the element registered? e.g. did you forget to include its html import?

Comment: @ebidel, that's a strong possibility. how do I register it?
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
I have that line of code?

Comment: @FlyingEmu, that would be ideal, ya. x-foo should take up h1's height and the width should be as wide as the text, or as wide as the screen, it doesn't matter to me at this point.

Comment: @ToughTimes Unfortunately x-foo does not represent the area of the elements in it's shadow DOM. In other words no matter what you do x-foo will always have a height and width of 0x0, it's just the way the code works unfortunately. Consider wrapping `h1` in `div` and using that as the container instead.

Comment: @ToughTimes interestingly "display: inline-block;" seems to work but not "display: block;".

Answer (score -1):

All polymer elements are set with 0 height and width, it's the contents inside it's shadow root which takes up the space. That is, **the polymer element does not represent the area take up by elements in it's shadow DOM.**

Comment: Thanks Flying Emu - the height and width are set to auto.

Comment: It's set to auto but it never changes it's width or height from 0, even if you add elements to it's light DOM.